# how to find which Android api I chose

Tags: android, android-studio

I created an App using Android Studio, I forgot which minimum API I chose!
how can I find out which min API I chose, I navigated the entire studio without luck

Comment: appcompact, support

Comment: Check at AndroidManifest file

Comment: So some of you don't have the time to answer dumb questions, but you have time to down vote it?!! easy with the down votes !! geeez

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`app/build.gradle` or `AndroidManifest.xml` contain this information.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> can also "Project Search" and you could have searched for "minimum"